# Android - creating a simplified spotify-like layout

Tags: android, android-layout, mobile, user-interface

I am developing an Android app and am a bit stuck on how I go about creating the layout I'm after. I said spotify-like (website not app) as I dont want the parallax effect. It's actually closer to http://www.poormet.com/.

What I have tested so far is a RelativeLayout with an ImageView and Listview (with transparent dividers) within it. This layout shows the image in the background between rows which is a step in the right direction. The issue is I'm at a loss as to how to get the images to change smoothly depending on what listrows are on screen.

Also, if I want to replicate the text over the images like poormet example mentioned above, then it seems to me I am going to have to have alternating transparent and not transparent rows.

Am I on the right track or am I approaching this problem the wrong way?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated!!!

(also, please let me know if what I have described doesn't make sense - more than happy to clarify)